# JavaScript regex: why match number with trailing decimal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been reading [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) by 
Douglas Crockford. In the section on regular expressions, there is the following regex to parse a number:

```
var parse_number = /^-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?$/i;
```

This regex is pretty straightforward to begin with, and Crockford breaks it down so that *almost* every aspect is very clear. However, there is one aspect that is not fully explained, and which I cannot figure out:

```
(?:\.\d*)?
```

His explanation, which I do understand, is:

> The `(?:... )?` indicates an optional noncapturing group...The group will
>   match a decimal point followed by zero or more digits.

The part that confuses me, and which is not explained, is *why* **zero or more digits** rather than **one or more digits**, i.e., why use `\d*` instead of `\d+` in this case? My intuition, which was confirmed through `.test`ing, is that the `parse_number` pattern described above will match not only strings like `'1.0'` - which you would likely want to match - but will also match strings like `'1.'` with a trailing decimal, which I cannot think of a use case for.

I assume there is a very good reason for using:

```
(?:\.\d*)?
```

instead of:

```
(?:\.\d+)?
```

but what might that reason be?

Comment: It is because `45.` is also considered valid decimal number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the JavaScript [*NumericLiteral* syntax production](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals), which allows for a trailing `.` with no digits after it. It's called out here:

> *DecimalLiteral* ::
>
> *DecimalIntegerLiteral* `.` *DecimalDigits*<sub>opt</sub> *ExponentPart*<sub>opt</sub>

Note how both the *DecimalDigits* and *ExponentPart* of that are optional.

This is entirely valid JavaScript:

```js
var a = 42.;
// -------^
console.log(a); // 42
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. The regex now makes sense to me as it matches the spec. Are there any differences between `42` and `42.` in JavaScript in that case? Your example code, and my cursory experiments in the console seem to indicate that they are identical, but if they are, why allow the trailing `.`? This seems to imply that there are times when you would want to use `42.` instead or `42`, or that a program might return `42.`. Python, the language I have most experience with, also allows `42.` (I just learned), but this translates to `42.0`; different from `42` in Python at least.

Comment: @elethan: There's no difference at all in the resulting value depending on whether you write `42` or `42.`. I can't say why they allowed a trailing `.` other than that not forbidding it is more flexible. It does lead to an interesting side-effect: You can't write `42.toFixed(2)` because it'll fail when parsing because the `.` is taken to be a decimal point, but you *can* write `42..toFixed(2)` -- because after the `42.`, it's a complete production, and so it's okay to use `.` to access a property... :-)